# Centering one div inside a parent container and placing another one right next to it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I'm trying to achieve a basic design.

I have one div container and want two containers inside that div:

Container: takes the full width of the screen/parent
Div 1: width of 200, centered inside the container.
Div 2: width of 100 and next to Div 1 on the right side with a margin on the left of 10px.

Anything I tried did push Div 1 away from the center, so that Div 1 and Div 2 were centered, but I did not achieve that Div 1 stay centered and Div 2 is just on the right side of it.

I am using React Native, so I tried the following:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
   <View style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200, height: 100}}></View>
   <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', marginLeft: 10, width: 200, height: 100}}></View>
</View
```

Any help and advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second div from the flow using `position: absolute`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container > * {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.two {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(calc(100% + 10px)); /* 100% + margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make a 3rd div as transparent. And, give parent .container `display:flex`;

```css
.container {background:yellow; height:100vh; width:100vw;display:flex; justify-content:center;}
.div1, .div2, .transparent {width:100px; height:100px;} 
.div1 {background:blue;}
.div2 {background:orange;margin-left:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="transparent"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```